# Need help calculating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1- \cos (t)}{t^\alpha} {\rm d}t$

Tags: integration

As part of an larger assignment I need to calculate the following integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(\lambda x)}{|\lambda|^\alpha} {\rm d}\lambda \quad x \in \mathbb{R}, \,1 < \alpha \leq 2
$$
I substituted $t=\lambda|x|$ to get
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1- \cos (t)}{t^\alpha} {\rm d}t
$$
But I have no idea how to continue. Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: $1<\alpha \leq 2$ so it converges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the following relation for the gamma function:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-bt}}{t^a}dt = \frac{\Gamma(1-a)}{b^{1-a}}$$
This gives:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{t^a}dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2t^a}dt = \Gamma(1-a)\frac{i^{1-a}+(-i)^{1-a}}{2}=\Gamma(1-a)\sin(a\pi /2)$$